# Disable azure devops repos with az-cli comand

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i need to disable repositories in azure devops, in gui we can do it on setting item, but...

is there an az-cli comand to disable repositories?

someting like "az repos settings ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The azure cli to update the repostiroy is "[az repos update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-update)", however it appears it only updates the default branch(--default-branch) or repository name "--name".

As an alternative, you can use rest api "[Repositories - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-respository-while-specifying-the-project)" to update the repo setting. Code sample:

```
Param(
   [string]$org = "orgname",
   [string]$project = "projectname",
   [string]$repositoryId = "repositoryid",
   [string]$token = "PAT"  
)
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$json = '{ "isDisabled" : "true" }'
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId" + "?api-version=6.0"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

[image]